# Blog Main Header Showing Recent Post Title Instead

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

My Wordpress blog works fine on the main page that shows all posts, however, when I click a category the most recent post's title becomes the main header and that post doesn't even show up in the blog post list of that category.

https://ibb.co/ebReRV

I spied on other people with the same theme as me and they have the same problem so I believe this is a problem with the original code. My theme's creator seems to have disappeared and hasn't responded to any of my messages.

**archive.php**

```
<section id="wp-main-content" class="clearfix main-page title-layout-standard">
<?php do_action( 'naturalfood_before_page_content' ); ?>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="main-page-content row">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content-page <?php echo esc_attr($main_content_config['class']); ?>">      
          <div id="wp-content" class="wp-content">  
                <?php get_template_part('templates/layout/archive') ?>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: You can verify this by commenting out this line of code: `<?php //do_action( 'naturalfood_before_page_content' ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Create Archive Page

Give Archive Page name is "archive.php".

Archive Page Structure Like this:

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<div class="entry-content">

<?php the_content(); ?>

/* Custom Archives Functions Go Below this line */



/* Custom Archives Functions Go Above this line */

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```